# Block with NSSet

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

can anyone tell me please why returnSet is returning as nil when there are lowercase characters in 'program'

I have stepped through and the NSLog is definitely picking the variables out but when it addObject: it just doesn't?

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableSet *returnSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];

    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        [program enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                if ([obj rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
                    NSLog(@"Variable: %@", obj);
                    [returnSet addObject:obj]; 
                }
            }
        }];
    }

    return returnSet;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code has no bug. It cannot return a value of `nil`.

Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: yes, I have taken the __block away and now it still works, perhaps it was just co-incidence; I've made that many changes now. As always learnt something new about when __block is used - thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your problem is an ARC memory management problem. The code you posted returns a non-owning reference to the set it creates. Unless you save it to a strong instance variable, it will be deallocated.